# Hash navigation crashes android browser

Tags: android, knockout.js

I am testing a html single page application using KnockoutJS and PagerJS. I am testing this app on my Xperia S (ICS 4.0.4) with the stock browser and i've had my application crash the browser with SIGSEV ([Full crash tombstone](http://pastebin.com/UDXz9k4f)), which is solved by commenting out this line (Even though it is severely detrimental to the user workflow of my app)

```
window.location.hash = "start";
```

This is start by the way:

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'start', title: 'Overview', afterShow: switchToOverview}">
    SNIP
</div>
```

Any ideas?

More details: the crash seems related to pushing the "Go" button on the virtual keyboard, as submitting the form with the submit button works fine.

Comment: Could you create a small jsfiddle or similar that triggers the crash? I don't got any Xperia S but hopefully I can find some simulator/emulator.

Comment: I will do once i get home. One meaningful find i got is that no other browser seems to crash when the hash location is changed.

Comment: I can't replicate the crash in any other code than my application, i am starting to think the browser itself is responsible. I've had no crashes on other browsers whatsoever.

Comment: Do you get the same crash if the hash is altered later on, instead of set directly using `window.location.hash`?

Comment: Maybe you can solve it using `setTimeout(function() { window.location.hash = '#some/page';}, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the hash with a hash `(#)` !

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location):

> `window.location.hash:`
>
> > the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.
> >     You can listen for the hashchange event to get notified of changes to the hash in supporting browsers.

Comment: I know i promised to accept this as answer but it turned out that it became a heisenbug when i tested your solution. Sorry.

Comment: Haha that's okay, I knew it probably couldn't be that simple!